# print the name gathered after a regular expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Ok so i need to gather the name of people in a txt file using perl, i can find the names and print them out with NAME: in front using a regular expression but i need to gather just the persons name I want to do this using regular expressions, because there is multiple different names to gather in each file.

Example of file input:

```
NAME: Bigelow, Patrick R                                              DATE: 28 Apr 2014
```

code so far:

```
if (/NAME:/){
    my @arr = /NAME:\s\S*\s\S*\s\S*/g or next;
    print "$_\n" for @arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use two lines of code, one for stripping out the names(between `Name: ... Date:`), and then split the names for comma.

```
my ($tmp) = /(?<=NAME: )(.*?)(?=\s+DATE:)/g or next;
my @arr = split(/,\s+/, $tmp);
```

Comment: The use of lookahead and lookbehind are superfluous in this example because you have an explicit capture block.   Additionally, don't need the /g flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `s/regex/replace/` to do what you want. I avoid using post fix loops (easy to miss and are a pain to fix when you add more lines) and the use of `$_` (does not improve readability, is inconstantly implemented, and is global in scope):

```
use strict;
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

use constant {
    TEXT_FILE  =>   'file.txt',
    NAME_LINE  =>   qr/^NAME:\s+/,
};

open my $name_fh, "<", TEXT_FILE;   # Autodie eliminates need for testing if this worked
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    next unless $line =~ NAME_LINE;  # Skip lines if they don't contain name
    ( my $name = $line ) =~ s/NAME:\s+(.+?)\s+DATE.*/$1/;
    say qq("$name");
}
close $name_fh;
```

The regular expresion `s/NAME:\s+(.+?) +DATE.*/$1/` needs a bit of explaining:

- The parentheses `(...)` are a capture group. I can refer to them by the `$1` on the substitution side.
- The `+?` is a *non greedy qualifier*. I am matching the smallest group I can that will match the regular expression. The trick is that `\s+DATE.*` will match as big as possible. Between the two, I eliminate all of the spaces from the end of the name to the `DATE` string this way. It's really not that efficient, but it works well.
- The qq(...) is just a fancy way of doing double quotes. It makes it easy to put quotes in your quotes this way.
- I use `say` instead of `print` because `say` will automatically add in the `\n` on the end. this becomes important where adding `. "\n"` to the end of something can cause problems.

For example:

```
print join ": ", @foo . "\n"; # Doesn't work.
say join ": ", @foo;          # This works fine.
```

Comment: This code looks great but there are some functions in it that I don't have available to me, AutoDie is one of them. Question though would this limit me from grabbing date later on in the code as well?

Comment: What version of Perl are you using? Autodie has been around since 5.12 and `feature qw(say)` since 5.10. Everything else should fine. If you're pre-5.10, use `print` (don't forget the `\n`) and check the return from `open` with `open ... or die qq(...);` syntax.