# Matching a perl regular expression over multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl

Ok so I have another question for help I need to gather an address in a txt file using perl, i have one place to grab the address from for each individual ticket in the file. My problem the multiple line that the that the address stretches over. I can get it to grab the first line but no matter what i do it never grabs the next line.

Sample text file

```
NAME     Sprinkle, Jonathan U  ADDRESS     16887 36 St NW    
                                           Calgary, AB T8O 0B0
```

Sample text file with apartment

```
NAME     Nguyen, Michael S     ADDRESS     100A  
                                           8447 149 Ave NW    
                                           Sherwood Park, AB T6J    0Z0
```

I need to be able to handle both an address with an apartment number as well as a house without an apartment number

my code so far(This can only grab the first line ):

```
if (/ADDRESS/){
    my @arr = /ADDRESS\s*\S*\s\S*\s\S*\s\S*\s*\n\s*\S*/g or next;
    print "$_\n" for @arr;
}
```

the output that this gives is:
`ADDRESS 16887 36 St NW`
Then it prints a newline here without the rest of the information

Comment: Consider activating either the `/s` or the `/m` tags

Comment: I have tried adding /m but when i did that the only things that it printed out was "1" @sshashank124

Comment: @Mitchk please try to use the formatting tools to make your post a bit more attractive and neat

Comment: @HamZa I have been trying to figure out how to use them right after i noticed how ugly it looked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [print the name gathered after a regular expression in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972188/print-the-name-gathered-after-a-regular-expression-in-perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note to the OP: It would help address a problem like this if you provided more than just a single record of data.*

However, when we combine the two examples of data, it becomes fairly apparently that the NAME and ADDRESS fields are aligned vertically.  This provides a fairly easy method of parsing because we basically just need to match an exact regular expression:

```
NAME     Sprinkle, Jonathan U  ADDRESS     16887 36 St NW    
                                           Calgary, AB T8O 0B0
NAME     Nguyen, Michael S     ADDRESS     100A  
                                           8447 149 Ave NW    
                                           Sherwood Park, AB T6J    0Z0
```

Using that as a baseline, the following script works for parsing four records:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @records;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^NAME     (.{22})ADDRESS     (.*)/) {
        push @records, {
            name => $1,
            address => $2,
        };

    } elsif (/^\s{43}(.*)/) {
        $records[-1]{address} .= "\n$1";

    } else {
        warn "Unknown format on $.: $_";
    }
}

# Strip extra spacing from all fields
for (@records) {
    for (values %$_) {
        s/\s+$//mg;
    }
}

# Output records for debugging
use Data::Dump;
dd \@records;

__DATA__
NAME     Sprinkle, Jonathan U  ADDRESS     16887 36 St NW    
                                           Calgary, AB T8O 0B0
NAME     Nguyen, Michael S     ADDRESS     100A  
                                           8447 149 Ave NW    
                                           Sherwood Park, AB T6J    0Z0
NAME     Sprinkle, Jonathan U  ADDRESS     16887 36 St NW    
                                           Calgary, AB T8O 0B0
NAME     Nguyen, Michael S     ADDRESS     100A  
                                           8447 149 Ave NW    
                                           Sherwood Park, AB T6J    0Z0
```

Outputs:

```
[
  {
    address => "16887 36 St NW\nCalgary, AB T8O 0B0",
    name => "Sprinkle, Jonathan U",
  },
  {
    address => "100A\n8447 149 Ave NW\nSherwood Park, AB T6J    0Z0",
    name => "Nguyen, Michael S",
  },
  {
    address => "16887 36 St NW\nCalgary, AB T8O 0B0",
    name => "Sprinkle, Jonathan U",
  },
  {
    address => "100A\n8447 149 Ave NW\nSherwood Park, AB T6J    0Z0",
    name => "Nguyen, Michael S",
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting only one line because of `my @arr = /ADDRESS\s*\S*\s\S*\s\S*\s\S*\s*\n\s*\S*/g or next;` each iteration you are setting the array equal to your last pattern match. You need to append to the line with a `push` like the following:

**DATA**

```
NAME     Sprinkle, Jonathan U  ADDRESS     16887 36 St NW    Calgary, AB T8O 0B0
NAME     Nguyen, Michael S     ADDRESS     100A  8447 149 Ave NW    Sherwood Park, AB T6J    0Z0
```

**EX:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @addresses;
while ( $test =~ /ADDRESS\s*([A-Za-z0-9,[:blank:]]+)/gxm ) {
    push @addresses, $1 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, neither of your samples show multiple lines.  So right away I can't see how to help you based on your examples.

Mostly though this is going to be a problem of the default input record separator.  What this means is that Perl's default behavior when you're processing a file is to give you one line at a time.  Unless you do something about that then you will never get what you want.

The variable that controls this is `$/`, so assuming `FILE` is your open filehandle you need to do something like this:

```
local $/;
my $contents = <FILE>;
```

Now `$contents` contains the whole contents of your file as a single string with all the `"\n"`s embedded.  So then you'll actually be able to try your match as you have it.

Comment: Sorry they at first did show multiple lines when it was edited it got changed. I fixed it to show how the file shows the information